# Tor fonts not displayed in Panopticlick

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, fingerprinting

[Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/) detects no fonts on my Tor browser. The standard should be Wingdings2 and Wingdings3.
I have disabled incognito mode and added Self-destructing cookies, uBlock Origin and changed the default font to serif (Firefox default). I tried adding the string `font.system.whitelist` to no avail. `Allow pages to use their own fonts` have been tested both on and off.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Disable the fingerprinting protections?

Comment: Fonts shown on Panopticlick appear indeed to be Wingdings 2 and Wingdings 3. It can only detect them when JavaScript is enabled though. FYI, installing addons and changing setting is generally not such a good idea if you don't want a distinct fingerprint.